# Return type of argmin method

Tags: python, numpy, types

As usual, I become quite confused about numpy data types.

Suppose I define a numpy array:

`>>> a = np.array([1.,2.,3.])`

Somewhere in the code I want to know if `a` is a numpy array versus some other type of data type. The following provides the answer:

`>>> print type(a)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

I did this from within iPython. It appears an object of type "type" is returned, but I don't really know how to process "type" objects in a program. I can also use isinstance to verify that `a` is a numpy array:

`>>> isinstance(a, np.ndarray)
True`

(Side question: how would I return an easily interpretable object to figure out what `a` is? The documentation says type returns the type of an object, but what kind of thing is a type of an object? It's not a string, or a number. It's some sort of object. I seem to be able to convert the type object to a string and then parse it with split() for example, but this seems dangerous. Is there sufficient documentation on the objects of type "type" that I could guarantee that when I pass it to str I get something I can parse in a standard way?)

Back to the main question.

I now use the argmin method on a:

`>>> f = a.argmin()`

I expected that the type of f is an integer, but its not. For example:

`>>> type(3)
int`

gives "int". But type f gives:

`>>> type(f)
numpy.int32`

I don't know what the answer numpy.int32 is telling me. It's not a numpy array:

`>>> isinstance(f, np.ndarray)
False`

But f is also not an integer. What is it? This is relevant, because I passed this numpy.int32 object to a function, and it created a mess. When I first convert to int, and then pass it to the function, everything worked fine. Clearly, the function wanted an int, but I passed it a numpy.int32 instead and got bad results.

The doc string for the argmin() method says it returns "indices". I am not sure what is. I assumed it would be an integer, or a numpy array of integers. But "indices" is neither. It's this "numpy.int32" thing. What is that?

Thanks for your help.

(Side discussion continued: I still seek a numpy function or method that returns the type of an object in some easily-interpretable form. type returns an object of type "type", but I don't know how to write a program that queries type objects. I don't really know what a type object is or how to interact with it. It would be great to have a numpy function that returns something simple, and tells me "this is a numpy array of floats" or "this is a scalar float" or "this is a numpy.int32" (whatever that is). I have yet to find a way to do this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check for a numpy ndarray's `.dtype` attribute. If you want a human to interpret the results, then things like `np.int32` mean "numpy integer type of 32 bits." If you want to know this programatically, then probably the best is to use `np.typecodes`:

```
>>> np.typecodes
{'All': '?bhilqpBHILQPefdgFDGSUVOMm', 'Complex': 'FDG', 'AllFloat': 'efdgFDG',
 'Integer': 'bhilqp', 'UnsignedInteger': 'BHILQP', 'Float': 'efdg',
 'Character': 'c', 'Datetime': 'Mm', 'AllInteger': 'bBhHiIlLqQpP'}
```

Each of those codes represents a different type:

```
>>> for t in np.typecodes['UnsignedInteger']:
...     print(np.dtype(t).name)
... 
uint8
uint16
uint32
uint32
uint64
uint64
```

Note that the return of e.g `np.dtype(...)` is the same that would be returned by `a.dtype` if `a` were an ndarray of that type.

Lastly, if you simply want to check whether it is an integer or a float, you can check the dtype's `.kind` attribute, which also return a single character:

```
>>> np.dtype(np.float32).kind
'f'
>>> np.dtype(np.int32).kind
'i'
>>> np.dtype(np.uint32).kind
'u'
>>> np.dtype(np.bool).kind
'b'
```

It is a little more complicated, so it may get confussing, but reading [the relevant part of the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) is probably a good idea.